# Detect ul list content change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

We have an unordered list with id #some-list. In our Backbone implementation, when certain data is returned, list entries are rendered and appended to the list and the list is displayed.

We want to detect when such change is completed using JQuery. We used `$(#some-list).ready()` and `$(#some-list).load()`, but it looks like they are not working.

What are some ways to capture such change? Could anyone shed some lights here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you didn't post any code so it's really hard to see guess where you fail.
But in general what i would do is trigger a custom event on the ajax callback (you do use ajax to get the content and appending it to the list right?).

for example:

```
loadData(){
  // invoke the ajax request
  var def = $.get(...);
  def.then(function(result){
    // $(#ul) append(result) ...  
    // now trigger the custom event  
    $(document).trigger('listRendred');
  });
}
```

Now on a different place or script you can listen to it:

```
$(document).on('listRendred', function(e){ // do what ever... })
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Out of curiosity, are there any best practices when triggering custom events?

Comment: @BoYuan Yes - best practice would be to NOT use jQuery DOM events as shown in this answer. Use Backbone's built in event API to trigger backbone events.  As shown in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46207471/2333214).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using BackboneJS you could try to listen to its events.

To find out which events you could use, try following code (replace my * placeholders first) and have a look inside your browser's console.

```
*backboneobject*.on("all", function(e) {
  console.log(e)
});
```

Afterwards just listen for the event by using

```
*backboneobject*.on("*yourevent*", function() {
  doStuff();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Sorry I am new to Backbone, what could be the backbone object from client side? Backbone? window.Backbone?

Comment: Just as @Sag1v stated its hard to give a good answer without any code. You probably have a collection of models retrieved by your loading function. So the code would be `nameofcollection.on("change", function(){ doStuff(); });`